# How to add pins to google map using jQuery and JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, google-maps

I am trying to add pins to a Google Map using postcodes stored in a Google Sheet. So far I have been able to access to the Postcodes in the spreadsheet using JSON:

```
$.getJSON('http://cors.io/?u=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1pksFEATRRWfOU27kylZ1WLBJIC-pMVxKk9YlCcDG0Kk/od6/public/values?alt=json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, v) {
        var data = $('<div class="listing">').append('<h4 id="bandb">' + v.gsx$postcode.$t + '</h4>');
        $('body').append(data);
    });
});
```

I am also able to add pins to a Google Map using the postcodes.

Example: http://codepen.io/aljohnstone/pen/eJOyrP

I am having trouble combining the two. I would like the `postcodes` variable in the Codepen to take the postcodes from my Google Sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example using the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    center: {
      lat: 54,
      lng: -3
    },
    zoom: 5
  });
  var i;
  var postcodes = [];
  $.getJSON('http://cors.io/?u=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1pksFEATRRWfOU27kylZ1WLBJIC-pMVxKk9YlCcDG0Kk/od6/public/values?alt=json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, v) {
      postcodes.push(v.gsx$postcode.$t);
    });
  }).done(function() {
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(54.00, -3.00));
    map.setZoom(5);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (i = 0; i < postcodes.length; i++) {
      geocoder.geocode({
        'address': "" + postcodes[i]
      }, (function(i) {
        return function(results, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: results[0].geometry.location,
              map: map,
              title: postcodes[i]
            });
            bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        }
      })(i));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 600px; height: 350px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
       var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
       var i;
       var postcodes = [];
       $.getJSON('http://cors.io/?u=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1pksFEATRRWfOU27kylZ1WLBJIC-pMVxKk9YlCcDG0Kk/od6/public/values?alt=json', function(data) {
         $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, v) 
         {
           postcodes.push(v.gsx$postcode.$t);
         });
       }).done(function()
       {
           map.setCenter(new GLatLng(54.00, -3.00), 5);
           for (i = 0; i < postcodes.length; i++) {
             geocoder.getLatLng(postcodes[i] + ', UK', function(point) {
               if (point) {
                 map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point));
               }
             });
           }
       });
});
</script>
```

Working example http://codepen.io/snm/pen/eJOVMY?editors=101

Comment: This code example is using the [deprecated and turned off Google Maps Javascript API v2](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-maps-api-2/info), which **should not be used for new code.**

Comment: i have just recreated the output with the scripts the @user3780099 has used in his codepen.